# Windows vs Linux vs. OS X Monero user distribution

Tags: operating-system, vps

Is there any data on the current distribution of Monero users by Operating system?

Useful data could include the following:

1. Download data from: https://getmonero.org/downloads/
2. Any estimates about how often each OS is used among users who build from source: https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero
3. Estimates (or self reported data) on the percentage of nodes hosted by VPS (which may also answer the OS question depending on the VPS plan chosen)
4. Estimates (or self reported data) on the percentage of miners by OS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downloads, attempts to build from source, VPS use, and mining do not not necessarily equate to OS usage. The Monero network does not reveal the OS of nodes submitting transactions.

However, it is very likely that there are far more Linux users (as a percentage of total users) as compared to most other Bitcoin based cryptocurrencies which have a easy to use QT wallet.

This is likely more true for users who are familiar with the command line and run their own full nodes (many Linix users) and less true for those who store their Monero on exchanges or rely on the MyMonero.com webwallet (less likely to be comfortable with Linux and the command line). Miners (ignoring those who purchase cloud mining) are probably more likely to be familiar with Linux than those who do not mine.

Comment: Furthermore, I've been unable to find a miner that Windows Defender (at least on Windows 10) doesn't block rather forcefully, so I suspect Windows 10 usage is pretty low.

Answer (score 9):

We don't log download stats from downloads.getmonero.org on purpose, but even if we did the stats would be skewed. Windows users, for instance, will almost unilaterally download a binary. A large portion of Linux users, on the other hand, will compile from source.

The only way to get this sort of breakdown would be to capture stats on all possible sources, and then we risk leaking user metadata that we'd rather not have.